# Rails App with Devise Based Authentication on Multiple Servers - Sign in issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, rubygems

I am using the [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication in my Rails app and it works fine.  So far we only had one server hosting the Rails application.

Now with AWS migration, we have two servers hosting the application.  The sign in process has broken and we cannot log in.  If we remove one server from the Load Balancer, it starts working again.  Adding the server back  breaks the login system.

We use ActiveRecord based authentication in a master-master configuration, viz. There are two DB servers in master-master mode that remain in sync.

Comment: What session store does your app use?

Comment: @MladenIlić ActiveRecord Session store.

Comment: Interesting problem. Do you have any more information about the error? Any error message? There were issues with Devise and CSRF protection, you could try disabling it to see if that's where the underlying bug is.

Comment: @MladenIlić We found the issue, sorry it was not related to Devise Gem.  Will post a detailed answer shortly.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you solved the issue. Looking forward to further details. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was not related to Devise Gem.  It was that the MySql database which is in master-master replication mode, did not replicate the data correctly.  The session id was being saved in one DB server but not the other.  Hence removing one App Server worked.

The remedy was to reconfigure the Database servers to act in master master mode.